# Windows form dataset

Tags: c#, winforms, dataset

I have created a dataset table.

What I want to achieve is that if I change some values and save them, I want saved values to be shown when I reopen the form.

[image]

i.e. If I change some value in Comission column and click save and close the form and reopen it I want to see the saved value.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Save as XML with schema

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.WriteXml(FILENAME, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
ds.ReadXml(FILENAME);
​
```